# USE of flag=check function to check the room status for a project of hotel room process

Tags: c++

My query is that when i am trying to use the check flag to check for the room status it gives up an error. However without it the code runs fine. The check(int) function has also been declared.
The code also saves the record and edits the logs accordingly could someone look and check to see what for the error. I am also attaching the compilation error for when the code is run with "flag=check(rn)"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpEqd.png)

```html
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

 
using namespace std;

class Hotel
{
    char name[30], address[50],phone[10];
     int idnum,rn,room_no;
;
     public:
        int check(int);         
    void getdata();     
    void showdata() const;  
    int getIDNum() const;
}; 

void Hotel::getdata()
{
  int check(int);           
    int flag;
    cout<<"Enter The Room NO :"; cin>>rn;
    /////flag=check(rn);   ???????? Not working
    if(flag)
cout<<"\nRoom is already booked! Choose another Room!";
else
{
    room_no=rn;
    cout<<"\nEnter The ID number of the Customer: ";
    cin>>idnum;
cout<<"\n\nEnter Customers Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,50);
    cout<<"\nEnter Address : ";
    cin>>address;
    cout<<"\nEnter Phone Number: ";
    cin>>phone;
}
}
 
void Hotel::showdata() const
{
cout<<"\nCustomer Details";
cout<<"\n----------------";
cout<<"\nName: "<<name;
cout<<"\nID No: "<<idnum;
cout<<"\nAddress: "<<address;
cout<<"\nPhone no: "<<phone;
cout<<"\nRoom no: "<<rn;    
}
  
 
int  Hotel::getIDNum() const
{
    return idnum;
}

void write_cust()
{
    Hotel cust;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Customer.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
    cust.getdata();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel));
    cout<<"\n\nCustomer record Has Been Created ";
    outFile.close();
    getch();
}
 
void display_all()
{
    Hotel cust;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Customer.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    cout<<"==============Records=============="<<endl<<endl;
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel)))
    {
        cust.showdata();
        cout<<"\n\n====================================\n";
    }
    inFile.close();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
 
void display_sp(int n)
{
    Hotel cust;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Customer.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be opened! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    bool flag=false;
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel)))
    {
        if(cust.getIDNum()==n)
        {
             cust.showdata();
             flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nrecord not exist";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
 void modify_Cust(int n)
{
    bool found=false;
    Hotel cust;
    fstream File;
    File.open("Customer.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
    if(!File)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be opened ! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
        while(!File.eof() && found==false)
    {
 
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel));
        if(cust.getIDNum()==n)
        {
            cust.showdata();
            cout<<"\n\nPlease Enter The New Details of Customer"<<endl;
            cust.getdata();
                int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(cust));
                File.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
                File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel));
                cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
                found=true;
        }
    }

 File.close();
    if(found==false)
        cout<<"\n\n Record Not Found ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
 
 
 
void delete_Cust(int n)
{
    Hotel cust;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Customer.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Temp.dat",ios::out);
    inFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel)))
    {
        if(cust.getIDNum()!=n)
    {
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&cust), sizeof(Hotel));
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    remove("Customer.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat","Customer.dat");
    cout<<"\n\n\tRecord Deleted ..";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
 
 

 int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    cout<<setprecision(2); 
    do
    {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\t///////////HOTEL MANAGEMENT/////////";
    cout<<"\n\n\t1.Book A Room";
    cout<<"\n\n\t2.DISPLAY ALL Customer RECORDS";
    cout<<"\n\n\t3.SEARCH Customer RECORD ";
    cout<<"\n\n\t4.MODIFY Customer RECORD";
    cout<<"\n\n\t5.DELETE Customer RECORD";
    cout<<"\n\n\t6.EXIT"<<endl;;
    cout<<"\t-------------------------------------";
    cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Your Choice (1-6): ";
    cin>>ch;
    system("cls");
    switch(ch)
    {
    case '1':   write_cust(); break;
    case '2':   display_all(); break;
    case '3':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Customer's ID number: "; cin>>num;
                display_sp(num); break;
    case '4':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Customer's ID number: "; cin>>num;
            modify_Cust(num);break;
    case '5':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Customer's ID number: "; cin>>num;
            delete_Cust(num);break;
    case '6':   exit(0);;
    default:    cout<<"\a"; 
        
    }
    }while(ch!='6');
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to implement the `check` function,

Comment: i have copied that down as an comment because the code wouldnt compile with it @molbdnilo

Comment: In `getdata`, you have declared a free function by that name. There is also a declaration of a member function by that name in `Hotel`. Neither function has an implementation.

Comment: @molbdnilo have removed that however its giving the exact same error

Comment: Because you still haven't provided a definition of that function. It doesn't appear by magic if you declare it.